# Display one result(cell) from mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to rack my brains on this one for a while and the documentation on both MySQL and MySQLi is confusing me. Would it be possible to get any help?

I have a table called track_table and it contains two rows hash and track

```
    hash              |  track
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd |  Azelia Banks - 1991
```

I want to display the track name but I don't know how to. I have tried 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' and various other functions but nothing. Here is the query I have so far.

```
    $hash = $_GET['sub'];

    $check_track = "SELECT track FROM track_table WHERE hash = '.$hash.' ";
    $track_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_track) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($track_res);
    echo $result['track'];
```

I just want to be able to display the track name on a webpage.

I know I haven't implemented any security features and I'm taking data straight from the user, I shall do this later, once I have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the `string-literal . variable . string-literal` part of your script.

```
if ( !isset($_GET['sub']) ) {
    die('missing paraemter sub');
}

$check_track = "
    SELECT
        track
    FROM
        track_table
    WHERE
        hash = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['sub'])."'
";
$track_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check_track) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($track_res);
if ( !$result ) {
    echo 'no such record';
}
else {
    echo $result['track'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution just now but its still failing to display the track name :(

Comment: Appologies, just check my Apache logs and it was a problem with connecting to the database. Your solution works perfect now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
$hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub']);

$check_track = "SELECT track FROM track_table WHERE hash = '.$hash.' ";
$track_res = mysql_query($check_track) or die (mysql_error());

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($track_res);
print_r($result);
```

be sure about the names of table, column or input type.
i hope it will help you.

Comment: OP asked for `mysqli`